# Catch exception when on PDO connection

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following connection being made using PDO. Obviously it won't connect as I've not specified host or database (or user or password)

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=', '', '');
```

..so how do I catch the exception? I'm trying something like this:

```
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=', '', '');
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

.. but no message is displayed. Why?

Comment: Try adding `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened.

Comment: Without specifying anything in the connection string, PDO will not attempt to connect to anything, thus no exception. Put anything in the connection string and you will see your exception.

Comment: Well if you want to catch PDO execption then catch `PDOException` instead of `Exception`.. makes sense?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using custom namespace? then you need to change

```
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

notice the backslash before Exception.

Comment: -1 The echo syntax he is using is correct. (http://php.net/echo) And the exception namespace is ROOT so you do not need the slash

Comment: @John You are wrong with `And the exception namespace is ROOT so you do not need the slash`. If the code runs in a context of a custom namespace, the \ is required to address the global namespace.

Comment: Where's the namespace he's using? He's not using one. You can also say maybe he has a database name of '' and a user of '' with a password of ''. It's a phantom solution that doesn't answer the question

Comment: @John Where would you expect the namespace declaration in that code snippet? It is likely that the code runs *indeed* in a custom namespace but the OP forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the attribute `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` in order to receive exceptions on a failing connection attempt:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=', '', '', array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
```

Check the manual page of [`PDO::__construct()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php) for more info.

Please also check @Ali's answer!